# Layout inflation issues: Two layouts are inflated in a fragment, instead of one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to open a fragment from my activity, but when I do both the Activity layout and fragment layout is inflated, I only want the fragment layout to display. Why is this?

Activity Code:

```
public class Login extends Activity {

public static String res="";
private EditText login_username,login_pass;
private TextView test_login;
private SharedPreferences sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

Button btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
login(login_username.getText().toString(),login_pass.getText().toString());
        }
    });
private void login(final String user,String pass){
    new   Login_Server("http://192.168.1.100/test/index.php/client_users/Login",user,pass).execute();
    final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    pd.show();

    final Timer tm=new Timer();
    tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
if (res.equals("login")) {
                        Index index = new Index();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction =     getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, index); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
                        transaction.commit();

                        tm.cancel();
                        res = "";

                    } 
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1, 1500);
}
```

Fragment code:

```
public class Index extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button Index,Share;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.index, container, false);

    Index=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.index_page);
    Share=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.share_page);
    btn_click();
    return rootview;
}

public void btn_click(){
    Index.setOnClickListener(this);
    Share.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.share_page:
            Share share_page = new Share();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, share_page); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
            transaction.commit();
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

xml layout fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:weightSum="100">

<include layout="@layout/main_index"></include>
<include layout="@layout/bottom_menu"></include>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide the XML layout code where the fragment container is inflated from?

Comment: this code show the index from fragment:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <include layout="@layout/main_index"></include>
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_menu"></include>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: in the <include> just some botton and textview are existing

Comment: I would highly suggest adding the code into the question rather than the comments and I still can't see the widget the with the id of R.id.content, can you post the XML where that resides?

Comment: if you mean android.R.id.content in my code i saw this code before, to use it in the fragment and i use it for all of my fragment and dont have any problem with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your login activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

inflates the activity layout

and on your fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.index, container, false);

    Index=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.index_page);
    Share=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.share_page);
    btn_click();
    return rootview;
}
```

inflates the fragment's layout

therefor you inflate 2 layouts

anyway if u wish to use the fragment layout allover the activity screen
u should change the activity layout to host a container with an ID
like in your code on the activity u have this line:

```
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, index);
```

you should just have a view on the activity layout with the id=content and make it match_parent on height and width 
this one should be the parent of all the other childs on the layout

that way the fragment will cover all of the activity layout when u replace the container

gl..